# Display special characters in highchart

Tags: html, highcharts

I want to display special characters in `plotLines.title` like

**JavaScript code**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            plotLines: [{
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                value: 100,
                label: {
                    text: 'ø 30d',
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -10
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }]
    });
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz6ap5tj/)

It works here but in my web page it didn't render correct.

Comment: what is the environment in which you are using this? like Angular js,backbone??

Comment: Could you recreate your unworking demo ?